# How to create a point layer from a one-to-many join?

Tags: qgis

I have two layers:

- One with geographical coordinates containing every address in the county and a unique identifier.
- The second contains a list of incidents with the unique identifier from the address layer.

I could join the incidents layer to the address layer and then query only those addresses that have an incident. However there could be multiple incidents at on address, so I need to join the address layer to the incidents table. This gives me a record for each incident and the X Y coordinates from the address layer.

How do I specify that this layer now contains points without writing an intermediate file and re importing?

The two original layers will change with time and I don't want to save intermediate files.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible out of the box.

I don't know how you are currently storing your address and incident data. I'd recommend to use a database where you can define a VIEW that joins incidents and addresses.